# Generar un vinculo en php de descarga de archivos, que cambie de color cuando se le haga click

Tags: php, base-de-datos, moodle

Buenos días. Mi intención con mi código es enviarle una lista de hipervínculos de descarga a un usuario. La idea es que se  cambie el fondo del hipervínculo cuando una persona haga clic y quede marcado (ya sea con el color de letra cambiado o que el vinculo tenga un color de fondo distinto).
Las condiciones de los if son irrelevantes (son las que puse en mi codigo) y la única linea que hay debajo de cada uno, me deja la variable $data->link como un vinculo clickeable. Hasta ahí todo normal, pero necesito que $data->link quede como un vinculo clickeable con las características que mencioné.

```
        <?php
                        if ($fd->componente == 'mod_resource'){
$data->link= preg_replace('!(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i','<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>',"$CFG->wwwroot/mod/resource/view.php?id=".$fd->idmodulocurso);
                            }


                            else if ($fd->componente == 'mod_folder'){
$data->link= preg_replace('!(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', "$CFG->wwwroot/pluginfile.php/". $fd->idcontexto . "/mod_folder/content/0/". rawurlencode($fd->nombrearchivo)) ;
                            }
            ?>
```

Todo esto esta en el contexto de una pagina de codigo, se las dejo por si ayuda a entender el contexto (una query en formato moodle a una base de datos)

```
<?php 
require (dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/config.php');
global $DB;

        global $DB;
        $query =        "SELECT     f.id AS id, 
                                    c.fullname AS nombrecurso, 
                                    c.shortname AS nombrecortocurso, 
                                    cx.contextlevel AS nivelcontexto, 
                                    f.contextid AS idcontexto, 
                                    f.filename AS nombrearchivo, 
                                    f.component AS componente, 
                                    cm.course AS idcurso,
                                    cm.id AS idmodulocurso
                        FROM            {files} f
                        INNER JOIN      {context} cx        ON (f.contextid = cx.id)
                        INNER JOIN      {course_modules} cm ON (cx.instanceid=cm.id)
                        INNER JOIN      {course} c          ON (cm.course=c.id) AND f.filename <> ? AND f.component <> ? AND f.timecreated > ?";
        $files_data=$DB->get_records_sql($query,array('.','user','0'));

        $table = new html_table();
        $table->head = array('File_name','Course_name','Link');
        foreach ($files_data as $fd) {
            $data = new stdClass();
            $data->nombre = $fd->nombrearchivo;
            $data->nombrecurso = $fd->nombrecurso;
                if ($fd->componente == 'mod_resource'){
                    $data->link= preg_replace('!(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', "$CFG->wwwroot/mod/resource/view.php?id=".$fd->idmodulocurso);
                }   
                else if ($fd->componente == 'mod_folder'){
                    $data->link= preg_replace('!(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', "$CFG->wwwroot/pluginfile.php/". $fd->idcontexto . "/mod_folder/content/0/". rawurlencode($fd->nombrearchivo)) ;
                }
        $table->data[] = array($data->nombre, $data->nombrecurso,$data->link);
        }
    echo html_writer::table($table);    




?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bueno, dada la información que proporcionas la repuesta que puedo darte es que uses CSS 3; te dejo el siguiente ejemplo a consideración:

```css
a:link div{
    color: blue;
    background-color: lightblue;
    padding:5px;
}
a:visited div {
    color: green;    background-color: blue;
}
a:hover div {
    color: hotpink;     background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com" targe="_blank"><div>Link a google</div></a><br />
<a href="http://referi.com" targe="_blank"><div>Link a referi</div></a><br />
<a href="http://random.com" targe="_blank"><div>Link a random</div></a>
```

Lo que sucede aquí es que cuando visitas un link es el browser quien recuerda esto, puedes aplicar una regla CSS a esta situación y si englobas un `<div>` dentro de tu tag `<a>` se aplica esta regla al elemento hijo; el tag `<div>`